# Firefox can't find Adobe reader when launched from TWIST/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, firefox, sikuli, adobe-reader

When I launch firefox from the command line, I am able to view PDF's in my browser. I am testing a GUI with Twist which is an IDE based on eclipse and using the sikuli driver. Before I run the test I close the browser. The line of code that opens the browser says: `App.open(PDF_ENABLED_BROWSER + " -new-window " + URL` When I try to open a PDF I get the following error, Could not launch Adobe Reader 9.5.1. Please make sure it exists in PATH variable in the environment. If the problem persists, please reinstall the application. I am running on RHEL and using Firefox 3.6.23, not by choice. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by adding the following 2 lines to my .bashrc file.
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mylocation/Adobe/Reader9/Browser/intellux
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`